# Webcam orientation and flip in Kurento (WebRTC)

Tags: orientation, webrtc, webcam, kurento

I am a newby in Kurento (WebRTC).
I want to use a webcam that is in portrait orientation as a mirror.
Basicly that means I need to rotate the webcamfeed 90 degrees and flip it.
How can this be done?

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the facingMode key to your constraints ([which is not yet implemented in Chrome for Android](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=290161)) like this, for instance

```
    video: {
        width: {min: 320, ideal: 1280, max: 1920},
        height: {min: 240, ideal: 720, max: 1080},
        framerate: 30,     // Shorthand for ideal.
        // facingMode: "environment" would be optional.
        facingMode: {exact: "user"}
    }});
```

Provided your pipeline is one webrtc to another, you would have to insert a GStreamer filter to rotate the image. This would do

```
    GStreamerFilter videoflip =  new GStreamerFilter.Builder(pipeline, "videoflip method=clockwise").withFilterType(FilterType.VIDEO).build();
    presenterWebrtc.connect(videoflip);
    videoflip.connect(viewerWebrtc);
```